# Dynamic filters shiny app with equal/common levels

Tags: r, dynamic, filter, shiny, subset

I'm trying to have an app with 3 dynamic filters where each filter is a subset of the previous.

I have partial success, however, since I have similar levels/factors for some of the data it seems this causing an issue with my filters outcome.

I can't seem to figure out how to solve the issue with the common levels for the "Spot" attribute.

Does anyone have any feedback?

Thanks!

My app:

```
library(rstudioapi)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(readxl)
library(DT)
library(devtools)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(rgl)
library(rglwidget)


col_1 <- c("A1","A1","A1", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1","C1","C1")
col_2 <- c("a",  "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "a",  "b", "c")
col_3 <- c("Benz",  "Audi", "Renault", "Ferrari", "Porsche", "Mercedes", "Benz", "Benz",  "Audi", "Renault")

data_1 <- data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
colnames(data_1) <- c("Building", "Spot", "Car")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filterCars <- reactive({
    filterCar <- data_1
    filterCar <- droplevels.data.frame(filterCar)
    return(filterCar)
  })
  
  filterBuilding <- reactive({
    unique(as.character(filterCars()$Building))
  })
  
  output$filterBuilding <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'filter_Building', 'Building',
                choices = sort(filterBuilding()),
                multiple = TRUE,
                width = "1250px",
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                selected = sort(as.character(filterCars()$Building)))
  })
  
  # # Subset dynamically the previous reactive filter #
  datasub1 <- reactive({
    data_1[data_1$Building == input$filter_Building,]
  })
  
  filterSpot <- reactive({
    unique(as.character(datasub1()$Spot))
  })
  
  output$filterSpot <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'filter_Spot', 'Spot',
                choices = sort(filterSpot()),
                multiple=TRUE,
                width = "1250px",
                options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                selected = sort(as.character(filterCars()$Spot)))
  })
  
  # Subset dynamically the previous reactive filter #
  datasub2 <- reactive({
    data_1[data_1$Spot == input$filter_Spot,]
  })

  filterBrand <- reactive({
    unique(as.character(datasub2()$Car))
  })

  output$filterBrand <- renderUI({
    pickerInput(inputId = 'filter_Brand', 'ID',
                choices = sort(filterBrand()),
                multiple = TRUE,
                width = "1250px",
                selected = NULL,
                options = list("max-options" = 4, `actions-box` = TRUE))
  })
  
  
   output$databaseCars <- DT::renderDT({

    #  Subset for plotly reactivity
    Filter1 <- droplevels.data.frame(data_1)
    Filter2 <- filter(Filter1,
                      Filter1$Building %in% input$filter_Building,
                      Filter1$Spot %in% input$filter_Spot,
                      Filter1$Car %in% input$filter_Brand)

    # Plot
    datatable(Filter2,
              filter="none",
              selection="none",
              escape=FALSE,
              rownames = FALSE,
              # colnames = c("", ""),
              autoHideNavigation = TRUE,
              style = 'bootstrap4',
              options = list(searching = FALSE, # remove search option
                             ordering = FALSE, # remove sort option
                             paging = FALSE,  # remove paging
                             info = FALSE # remove bottom information
              )) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 1, fontWeight = 'bold', `text-align` = 'left') # text to bold and lign left in first column
  })
  
}

# User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             uiOutput("filterBuilding")
      )),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             uiOutput("filterSpot")
      )),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             uiOutput("filterBrand")
      )),
    
    p(DTOutput('databaseCars'))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues I've spotted:

- you can have several factors/selections per variable, therefore you need to use `%in%` instead of `==` for the filtering
- for the brands, you've set `selected = NULL`, therefore no brand was selected by default
- in general, it is recommend to create the UI elements in the `ui` part and update them with `updatePickerInput` instead of using `renderUI`, because then all rendering has to be done server side, which can slow the app down (especially if you have a several parallel users, as it is only served by one `R` process

Here is my take:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(shinyWidgets)


col_1 <- c("A1","A1","A1", "A2", "A2", "B1", "B2", "C1","C1","C1")
col_2 <- c("a",  "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "b", "a",  "b", "c")
col_3 <- c("Benz",  "Audi", "Renault", "Ferrari", "Porsche", "Mercedes", "Benz", "Benz",  "Audi", "Renault")

data_1 <- data.frame(col_1, col_2, col_3, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
colnames(data_1) <- c("Building", "Spot", "Car")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  filterCars <- reactive({
    filterCar <- data_1
    filterCar <- droplevels.data.frame(filterCar)
    return(filterCar)
  })
  
  
  filterBuilding <- reactive({
    unique(as.character(filterCars()$Building))
  })
  
  observeEvent(filterBuilding(), {
    updatePickerInput(session,
                      "filter_Building",
                      choices = filterBuilding(),
                      selected = sort(filterBuilding()))
  })
  
  # # Subset dynamically the previous reactive filter #
  datasub1 <- reactive({
    data_1[data_1$Building %in% input$filter_Building,]
  })
  
  filterSpot <- reactive({
    unique(as.character(datasub1()$Spot))
  })
  
  observeEvent(filterSpot(), {
    updatePickerInput(session,
                      "filter_Spot",
                      choices = sort(filterSpot()),
                      selected = sort(filterSpot()))
  })
  
  # Subset dynamically the previous reactive filter #
  datasub2 <- reactive({
    # browser()
    data_1[data_1$Spot %in% input$filter_Spot,]
  })
  
  filterBrand <- reactive({
    unique(as.character(datasub2()$Car))
  })
  
  observeEvent(filterBrand(), {
    updatePickerInput(session,
                      "filter_Brand",
                      choices = sort(filterBrand()),
                      selected = sort(filterBrand()))
  })
  
  
  output$databaseCars <- DT::renderDT({
    
    #  Subset for plotly reactivity
    Filter1 <- droplevels.data.frame(data_1)
    Filter2 <- filter(Filter1,
                      Filter1$Building %in% input$filter_Building,
                      Filter1$Spot %in% input$filter_Spot,
                      Filter1$Car %in% input$filter_Brand)
    
    # Plot
    datatable(Filter2,
              filter="none",
              selection="none",
              escape=FALSE,
              rownames = FALSE,
              # colnames = c("", ""),
              autoHideNavigation = TRUE,
              style = 'bootstrap4',
              options = list(searching = FALSE, # remove search option
                             ordering = FALSE, # remove sort option
                             paging = FALSE,  # remove paging
                             info = FALSE # remove bottom information
              )) %>%
      formatStyle(columns = 1, fontWeight = 'bold', `text-align` = 'left') # text to bold and lign left in first column
  })
  
}

# User Interface
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  mainPanel(
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             pickerInput(inputId = 'filter_Building', 'Building',
                         choices = NULL,
                         multiple = TRUE,
                         width = "1250px",
                         options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                         selected = NULL)
      )),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             pickerInput(inputId = 'filter_Spot', 'Spot',
                         choices = NULL,
                         multiple=TRUE,
                         width = "1250px",
                         options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),
                         selected = NULL)
      )),
    
    fluidRow(
      column(12,
             pickerInput(inputId = 'filter_Brand', 'ID',
                         choices = NULL,
                         multiple = TRUE,
                         width = "1250px",
                         selected = NULL,
                         options = list("max-options" = 4, `actions-box` = TRUE))
      )),
    
    p(DTOutput('databaseCars'))
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hello starja, thanks for the reply! Great stuff, it solves my issue. If I may, just a follow up comment/question? Is there a way to make the common Line values (a,b,c) for Building A and C as independent factors/levels?

Comment: sorry, I don't get what you mean by that. Do you want to extract the letters in "A1", "C1" etc. as its own variable?

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. For the dataframe I have for Building A1, lines "a", "b" and "c". It is the same for Building "C1". When we select these two building in the filter, the Line filter gets the choices "a", "b" and "c" which have the same designation for both buildings in spite being different. So my question is if it is possible to have levels with the same name but still being able to differentiate between them, i.e., "a","a", "b","b", "c","c".

Comment: I think it's not possible to have different factor levels with the same name. If you want to separate them, you could think of 1.) give them different names from the beginning on or 2.) make different inputs for the Lines for every building selected (however, this complicates things then)