# Shiny-R multiple filters in a data set, each new filter taking into account the other filters

Tags: r, filter, shiny

I have a data set like that:

| product_id | subfamily | family |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | alpha | A |
| 002 | beta | A |
| 034 | gamma | B |
| 078 | gamma | B |
| 098 | beta | A |
| 021 | epsilon | B |

where each row is a product and products are classified in their subfamilies and families. There are just two families, A and B. A has specific subfamilies which cannot be in family B and viceversa. The same happens with the products, the products in one subfamily cannot be in other subfamilies.

The thing is, I wanna have more than one filter, so for example if in the first filter I choose family A and I add a second filter based on subfamily, the options in subfamily will just be "alpha" and "beta", gamma and epsilon shouldn't appear because I would have already filtered by family A.

Is this possible? Right now I can add multiple filters but all the options appear so the user can filter in criteria which are not compatible (for example selecting family A and then selecting subfamily gamma, this shouldn't be possible).

Thanks!

Comment: My answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584478/how-to-update-shiny-module-with-reactive-dataframe-from-another-module/68594560#68594560) question shows you the technique you need: use `updateSelectinput` inside an `observeEvent` to change the choices available in the sub-family filter whenever the value of the family filter changes.  The focus of the question I link to is the use of modules, but the same approach will work here.

Comment: Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65309601/dynamic-filters-shiny-app-with-equal-common-levels) might be useful if you wish to use non-modules approach.

Comment: thanks, I will take a look in both solutions and will give feedback.